# Oauth2 gmail SMTP Authentication Error with phpmailer

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail

It's really a night mare. I don't know why I'm getting this for last 24 hours. Any help much appreciated please.

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP w23sm28778307wmd.1 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO cslexicon.tk
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [31.170.164.33]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO cslexicon.tk
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [31.170.164.33]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1zc3Nzc2F0aHlhYTY3QGdtYWlsLmNvbQFhdXRoPUJlYXJlciB5YTI5LmFRS2E2OC1qUmZsenhhYnE1YmkxNWlYcUtOa1VmTjdJZ3NBT2dLYU1uekhpR2I0NVV4dm9GNWozcDZoZGp3LXZtTjEyVEEBAQ==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 w23sm28778307wmd.1 - gsmtp
SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 w23sm28778307wmd.1 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I used league/oauth2-client, league/oauth2-google and got refresh token.

ClientID, Secret Code and Refresh code everything seems fine in my phpmailer code.

Followed everything at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257

Still, stuck here for very long time.

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @hgolov , Would you please brief your issue. 
I did this a long time ago. Need some more details.

Comment: I created a project in google developers, enabled gmail api, add credentials, and got the refresh token. However, when I try to actually send an email I get the same errors output as you did above. Do you by any chance remember what helped?

Comment: yes I do remember. But, one final check. Did you use league/oauth2-client and league/oauth2-google for getting refresh token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using league/oauth2-client and league/oauth2-google,

you will get the following prompt by default on getting refresh token.

[image: Image 1 - Initial]

But, these permissions do not allow you to send emails.

So you apply a simple quick fix.

At this stage, move your eyes towards the url in the address bar.

Analyze it closely and somewhere you find this,

> &scope=**email+openid+profile**&response_type

Change the scope to the following and don't touch the remaining part,

> &scope=**https://mail.google.com/**&response_type

Now, go to this new modified url. You will get a prompt like this,

[image: Image 2 - Final]

Click Allow and you are Good to go.

Comment: I was getting the same error as the OP. I was using the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send" because I only needed to send mail, not read/manage mail. Turns out, this scope isn't enough for SMTP access. You need the full "https://mail.google.com/" scope for XOAUTH2 in SMTP to work. - Edit: SF decided to parse the scopes as links, but I don't know how to prevent that. You get the idea either way.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem. however it can be solved by go to Account Settings and remove permission and then grant permission again.[image]

hope it will work with you too

Comment: It does help, but I have to do it over and over again. Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please go and check your scopes if you are dealing with SMTP
please add this in the scope **https://mail.google.com/**